# Change controller model template in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'd like to know if there is any way to change the basic template for the controller and the model in `laravel5.4`. I mean when I run:

```
php artisan make:controller ControllerName --resource
```

it will generate this:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 class UsersController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('users.index');
}
public function create()
{

}
public function store(Request $request)
{

}
public function show($id)
{

}
public function edit($id)
{

}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

}
public function destroy($id)
{

}
}
```

I need to change this template for anything I want to change the model as well.

Comment: You could make your own custom Artisan command that mimics the functionality. Here's the source of the built-in one: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3f8dff8279a10403dce1349e8c67463dc8cb1c1f/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.php

Comment: you cold do smth like this php artisn make:controller ControllerName  then u can modify routes and models, methods as u want. I dont know if I get it right ur question.

Comment: i need to change the template like public function index(){} i want it to generate like public function index1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was no way in `Laravel 5`, but from `laravel 7` you can [customize the stubs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#stub-customization)

Execute this command to publish all available stubs for customization

```
php artisan stub:publish
```

When we publish stub then all files of stub will be located within a `stubs` directory in the root of your application.

You can now edit all `.stub` files and customize your project files

I also suggest you read this blog post:

https://arievisser.com/blog/how-to-use-stub-customization-in-laravel/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't any "proper" way to do this.

The best solution, as mentioned in the comments, would be to create your own Command which would create the necessary file for you. You can find documentation for writing custom commands here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-commands