# Is it possible to configure brackets position in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i'm newbie in Laravel just practicing with some tutorial videos and i'm wondering if it is possible to configure the brackets position when i use the artisan commands.

For example when i create new controller using artisan make:controller it makes

```php
class Controller extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

What i want is the brackets places right next to the class declaration not in the new line like above. To be more specific

```php
Class Controller extends Controller{

    //
}
```

This is what i want. Is it possible to configure the brackets position?

I've googled a lot and read documentation but couldn't find any of information about it.

**--Edited--**

Thanks to you guys i know it's not Laravel problem and it can be configured in code editor.

I'm using vs code and have installed several php formatter but it seems all of them follow the PSR-2 styles.

I found JS configuration for its brackets position  but couldn't find for PHP 
i know it's not even problem i just don't like this format

Comment: It has nothing to do with laravel. You need to define code formatting in your code editor (i.e phpstorm, vscode etc).

Comment: You can change this in your code editor

Comment: Don't waste time, neither this is gonna ask in interviews nor in coding it's gonna affect much. Better install some plugins and format as per your convenience.

Comment: The reason the files are set up like this is so that they follow PSR-2 https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: @Rwd I'm using vs code right now and installed several formatter i think all of them follow that PSR-2 code styles... then can't i configure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change controller model template in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851361/change-controller-model-template-in-laravel)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd The latest Laravel 5.8.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the stubs that Laravel generates follow [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) so making this change would break that.

---

To override the controller code that Laravel generates with `make:controller` you're going to have to override the `ControllerMakeCommand` and copy the default stubs you want to edit.

The stubs for this command have changed quite a bit with the different versions of Laravel so it will require a bit of copy and paste to ensure it works correctly.

**Extend the `ControllerMakeCommand`**

Inside your `app/Console/Commands` directory create `ControllerMakeCommand.php` and add the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Routing\Console\ControllerMakeCommand as BaseCommand;

class ControllerMakeCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    //
}
```

---

**Add the `getStub` method**

Find the `getStub()` method in the `Illuminate\Routing\Console\ControllerMakeCommand` and copy that into your newly created `ControllerMakeCommand`.

---

**Copy the default stubs**

Copy

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/stubs
```

to

```
App/Console/Commands/stubs
```

(you don't have to copy all of the files inside it, just the `controller.*` that you want to override).

Change the formatting of the files as you see fit.

---

**Laravel <=5.4**

If you're using Laravel <=5.4 commands are not automatically loaded for you so you're going to have to tell Laravel that you want to use this command.

In your `App\Console\Kernel.php` add your new class to the `$commands` array e.g.:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\ControllerMakeCommand::class
];
```

---

**NB** Obviously, feel free to store the stubs wherever you want just make sure you update the paths in your new `ControllerMakeCommand`.